# Postgres select next following timestamp very slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, timestamp

I want to find for each timestamp in my table the next following one. The query works fine on a very small dataset (20 rows) but when I use it for a dataset with over 25000 rows it is extremely slow. Even after waiting several minutes I still get no result. Is there any way to improve the performance of my query?

```
SELECT
  mytime,
  (SELECT
    MIN(mytime)
   FROM mydata sub
   WHERE sub.mytime > main.mytime)
   AS nexttime
FROM mydata AS main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function to get a value from the next record in your result set. Combine this with sorting by your timestamp to achieve the same functionality.

```
select
    mytime,
    lead(mytime) over(order by mytime asc) as nexttime
from
    mydata
```

- [Window function overview](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)
- [Window functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

Comment: But I don't get the next closest timestemp I get the timestemp from the next record

Comment: @Matthias If you sort by the timestamp - that should be the same thing

Comment: thank you very much it wokrs with adding a order by timestamp in over()

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    mytime,
    lead(mytime) over(order by mytime asc) as nexttime
from
    mydata
order by
    mytime asc
```